# Unity3d error CS0103: The name `PeerState' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, photon

I got this error i cant really fix it i dont know what does it want me to do .
here is the code if you need more of the codes tell me if they will help you solve it .

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;


public class LobbyMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    //private string[]FirstName = new string[7]{"Clever", "Cunning", "Wise", "Awesome", "Amazing", "Dark", "Heroic"};
    //private string[]LastName = new string[7]{"Rogue", "Wizard", "Mage", "Summoner", "Warrior", "Assassin", "Ranger"};
    private string roomName = "myRoom";
    private bool MessageRoomNameTaken = false;
    private float MessageRoomTakenTimeToDisplay = 0;
    private Vector2 scrollPos = Vector2.zero;

    private bool connectFailed = false;

    public static readonly string SceneNameMenu = "LobbyScene";

    public static readonly string SceneNameGame = "GameScene";

    public void Awake()
    {
        // this makes sure we can use PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel() on the master client and all clients in the same room sync their level automatically
        PhotonNetwork.automaticallySyncScene = true;

        // the following line checks if this client was just created (and not yet online). if so, we connect
        if (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed == PeerState.PeerCreated)
        {
            // Connect to the photon master-server. We use the settings saved in PhotonServerSettings (a .asset file in this project)
            PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("1.0");
        }

        // generate a name for this player, if none is assigned yet
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PhotonNetwork.playerName))
        {
            //PhotonNetwork.playerName = "Guest" + Random.Range(1, 9999);
            //PhotonNetwork.playerName = FirstName[Random.Range(0, 6)] + " " + LastName[Random.Range(0, 6)];
            PhotonNetwork.playerName = MainMenu.username;
        }

        // if you wanted more debug out, turn this on:
        // PhotonNetwork.logLevel = NetworkLogLevel.Full;
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!PhotonNetwork.connected)
        {
            if (PhotonNetwork.connecting)
            {
                GUILayout.Label("Connecting to: " + PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                GUILayout.Label("Not connected. Check console output. Detailed connection state: " + PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed + " Server: " + PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress);
            }

            if (this.connectFailed)
            {
                GUILayout.Label("Connection failed. Check setup and use Setup Wizard to fix configuration.");
                GUILayout.Label(String.Format("Server: {0}", new object[] {PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress}));
                GUILayout.Label("AppId: " + PhotonNetwork.PhotonServerSettings.AppID);

                if (GUILayout.Button("Try Again", GUILayout.Width(100)))
                {
                    this.connectFailed = false;
                    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("1.0");
                }
            }

            return;
        }




        GUI.skin.box.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width - 400) / 2, (Screen.height - 350) / 2, 400, 300), "Join or Create a Room");
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect((Screen.width - 400) / 2, (Screen.height - 350) / 2, 400, 300));

        GUILayout.Space(25);

        // Player name
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("Player name:", GUILayout.Width(100));
        GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.playerName);
        //PhotonNetwork.playerName = GUILayout.TextField(PhotonNetwork.playerName);
        GUILayout.Space(105);
        if (GUI.changed)
        {
            // Save name
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("playerName", PhotonNetwork.playerName);
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Space(15);

        // Join room by title
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("Roomname:", GUILayout.Width(100));
        this.roomName = GUILayout.TextField(this.roomName);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Create Room", GUILayout.Width(100)))
        {

            foreach (RoomInfo roomInfo in PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList())
            {
                if (roomInfo.name == this.roomName) {MessageRoomNameTaken = true; break;}

            }
            if (MessageRoomNameTaken==false) PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(this.roomName, new RoomOptions() { maxPlayers = 2 }, null);

            Debug.Log("OnJoinedRoom");

        }



        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        // Create a room (fails if exist!)
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        //this.roomName = GUILayout.TextField(this.roomName);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Join Room", GUILayout.Width(100)))
        {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(this.roomName);
        }

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();


        GUILayout.Space(15);

        // Join random room
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.countOfPlayers + " users are online in " + PhotonNetwork.countOfRooms + " rooms.");
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Join Random", GUILayout.Width(100)))
        {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
        }


        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Space(15);
        if (PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList().Length == 0)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Currently no games are available.");
            GUILayout.Label("Rooms will be listed here, when they become available.");
        }
        else
        {
            int roomcount = PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList().Length;
            if (roomcount==1 )GUILayout.Label("1 room is currently available:");
            else GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList().Length + " rooms are currently available:");
            // Room listing: simply call GetRoomList: no need to fetch/poll whatever!
            this.scrollPos = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(this.scrollPos);
            foreach (RoomInfo roomInfo in PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList())
            {
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                GUILayout.Label(roomInfo.name + " " + roomInfo.playerCount + "/" + roomInfo.maxPlayers);
                if (GUILayout.Button("Join"))
                {
                    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(roomInfo.name);

                }

                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }

            GUILayout.EndScrollView();
        }

        GUILayout.EndArea();

        if (MessageRoomNameTaken == true) {

            MessageRoomTakenTimeToDisplay = 5; // we will display the warning for this number of seconds
            MessageRoomNameTaken = false;
        }
        if (MessageRoomTakenTimeToDisplay >0 ) { GUI.contentColor = Color.red;  
            GUI.Label(new Rect(400,50,300,60), "The room with this name already exists");
            MessageRoomTakenTimeToDisplay = MessageRoomTakenTimeToDisplay - Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    // We have two options here: we either joined(by title, list or random) or created a room.
    public void OnJoinedRoom()
    {

        Debug.Log("OnJoinedRoom");

    }

    public void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCreatedRoom");
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(SceneNameGame);
    }

    public void OnDisconnectedFromPhoton()
    {
        Debug.Log("Disconnected from Photon.");
    }

    public void OnFailedToConnectToPhoton(object parameters)
    {
        this.connectFailed = true;
        Debug.Log("OnFailedToConnectToPhoton. StatusCode: " + parameters + " ServerAddress: " + PhotonNetwork.networkingPeer.ServerAddress);
    }
}
```

i used photon network so yea . so please just rewrite or fix it or atleast tell me what to do i have no clue .

```
// the following line checks if this client was just created (and not yet online). if so, we connect
    if (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed == PeerState.PeerCreated)
    {
        // Connect to the photon master-server. We use the settings saved in PhotonServerSettings (a .asset file in this project)
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("1.0");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the docs for PhotonNetwork you'll see that the `PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed` static property returns a `ClientState` enum value (so not a `PeerState`).

**Source:** https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/class_photon_network.html

And here is the `enum` documentation:  [Enum Documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/group__public_api.html#ga8d4a6786d6193f0e6245c44e4a7bb4a0)

So, change:

```
if (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed == PeerState.PeerCreated)
```

to

```
if (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed == ClientState.PeerCreated)
```

Comment: It use to be `PeerState.PeerCreated`. I believe it got renamed after some update or something.